Ubuntu 24.04 Instability After BIOS Update: Random reboots
I’ve been experiencing significant system instability on my Ubuntu 24.04 machine after a recent BIOS update. The system randomly resets itself, and the logs show various errors. I’m hoping to get some guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve these issues.
System Information:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (Previously Ubuntu 22.04 with the same issue)
Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z790 GAMING X AX DDR5 LGA1700 (Rev 1.1)
CPU: Intel i7-13700k
BIOS Version: Updated to F11d (latest) from Gigabyte’s website due to issues with microcode for 13th and 14th generation Intel processors. The problem started after updating to F11c, and F11d did not resolve it.
Dual Boot: Windows and Ubuntu (Issue does not appear on Windows, at least not yet)

Issue Description:
Since updating the BIOS, my system has been crashing randomly, and the logs are filled with various errors. I’ve tried resetting the BIOS to its default settings, but the issue persists. The crashes occur at random moments, even when the system is idle, with no applications running. Here’s a snapshot of the errors occurring shortly after boot:
$journalctl --since "2024-08-14 12:15:00" --until "2024-08-14 12:34:00" -p 0..3                                     

sie 14 12:16:17 BMO kernel: i2c i2c-1: Invalid 7-bit I2C address 0xffff
sie 14 12:16:18 BMO kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
sie 14 12:16:18 BMO kernel: 
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO bluetoothd[1234]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO bluetoothd[1234]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
sie 14 12:16:29 BMO gdm-password][2251]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2688.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2685.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2682.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2942.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2950.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

Troubleshooting Steps Taken So Far:

I2C: Running i2cdetect -y -r 1 shows a device at address 0x48, but the Invalid 7-bit I2C address 0xffff error persists.

sudo i2cdetect -y -r 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 


WiFi: The Intel WiFi card (iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination) continues to show errors even with updated drivers.
Bluetooth: Reinstalling bluez did not resolve the Bluetooth errors related to malformed MSFT vendor events.
GNOME Keyring: Multiple GNOME Keyring components fail to start, affecting other system processes.
NVIDIA DRM: The DRM module for NVIDIA (nv_drm_master_set) fails to grab modeset ownership, potentially causing graphical instability.
Memtest86+: Passed without errors, so RAM issues are unlikely.
Temperatures: I’ve been monitoring component temperatures closely, and none of them appear to be overheating.

Additional Information:

Dual Boot: I have a dual-boot setup with Windows, and this issue does not occur on Windows (at least, not yet).
BIOS Reset: I’ve reset the BIOS to its default settings, but the issue persists.
Random Ubuntu reboots: The system reboot itself randomly, even when idle with no applications running.
Previous Ubuntu Version: The problem started on Ubuntu 22.04 after the BIOS update, so I reinstall to Ubuntu 24.04, but the issue remains.

Request for Help:
I’m looking for:

Guidance on identifying which of these errors might be causing the system resets.
Could the BIOS update have introduced hardware or firmware incompatibilities with the current Ubuntu kernel?
What steps can I take to isolate whether this is a hardware or software issue?

Has anyone encountered similar issues post-BIOS update, and if so, how were they resolved? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

As this is a hardware issue there is noting in the OS that can be done to assist you. This is something you need to address with Gigabyte.

I just wanted to know if this is a hardware issue or something on the software side that I can't see. Unfortunately I don't have a clear declaration from the logs that it's anything on the hardware side, so I don't know who to go to for help anymore. According to you, can any of these logs trigger a reboot?

As I already said contact Gigabyte. It is clearly a hardware issue. You said yourself after you updated the BIOS, a piece of the hardware, the problem started. Why would the software logs tell you about something you did to the BIOS?

but isn't it that if on windows the problem doesn't occur - the problem is ubuntu?

just having the same issue! I have gigabyte z790 X AX and updated the bios to f11d and been suffering random reboots on both linux and windows. Its definitely a Bios update problem, and its definitely not a unbuntu problem with the kernel as it also affects windows. Unfortunately the bios could not be dialled back as it contained microcode for the processor.
Its a pain, Im having to go to my PC dealer and get another motherboard. Eventually it will get patched out but for how long? knowing Gigabyte, months.
Im getting an MSI board, sick of this lack of support.

guys!
I have 1:1 the same error logs. With Ubuntu  24.04 and also 24.10.
I have a gigabyte z790 aorus elite ax rev 1.0. Intel I9 13900K and a gigabyte rtx4090 gaming oc rev1.
So I recently upgraded the bios to f12 with the new intel microcode. But I had the same issues with the bios versions before.
So my theory is that there is something corrupted in the motherboard's firmware's nvram. As the errors are persistent to bios updates and cmos clearing.
I ran the Firmware Test Suite (fwts) and the output showed me several errors. I had 1 high failure, 2 medium failures and 12 low failures.
High failures: 1 dmicheck: Illegal zero mapped address range for Memory Array Mapped Address (Type 19) @ 0x35a3dafd
The two medium failures were related to  Windows management Instrumentalisation. Which I never made knowingly use of. I had Windows 11 installed though.
The 12 low failures complained about missing strings for part serial numbers, manufacture information e.g.
I found this device  related to i2c-2:
Name: \SB .RHPX. DSD Device Properties UUID: Package: Key: bus-I2C-I2C1 Value: 0x00000000 Key: bus-I2C-I2C2 Value: 0x00000001
I think this device related to rhproxy.
That's what I found out so far. I am looking right now for a way to fix firmware.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/783192/636497
Wonderful man left a solution that works perfectly for me too! I hope it works for you too :)
